# Contradictory Properties of Mercuric Cyanide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility, electrolysis

It is said that mercuric cyanide [$\ce{Hg(CN)_2}$]  is water soluble and also is a non-electrolyte.

How is this possible?

Comment: It does not dissociate into ions? It is not a salt?

Comment: Would be nice to add a reference rather than state "it is said..." Just because *someone* says so doesn't make it true. Then again Maurice's answer seems a pretty convincing explanation of why it might be true.

Comment: The simple answer is that it is not a ionic compound.

Comment: @BuckThorn I didn't add any references as almost all of the information I found was word-of-mouth and the rest were too vague or indirect to be cited.[This](http://actachemscand.dk/pdf/acta_vol_12_p1568-1574.pdf) paper simply speculates based on experimental data.

Comment: Sugar is also water-soluble and a non-electrolyte.  Most acids that are water soluble are only weak acids and thus close to being non-electrolytes.  What's the fuss over this one case out of many?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mercury cyanide behaves like Mercury chloride $\ce{HgCl_2}$. Both are soluble in water, and both do not dissociate in water. These compounds are not salts. The bonds $\ce{Hg-Cl}$ or $\ce{Hg-CN}$ are more covalent than ionic. When the atom Hg is included in compounds it often behaves as a non-metal.

This is due to a relativistic effect. In all elements with atomic number higher than $70$, the outer electrons move at a speed that is not far from *c*, the velocity of light in vacuum. Of course everybody knows that electrons do not move like planets in the atom. But the relativistic corrections are significant "as if" the electrons were moving. And one of the effect due to relativity is that the length decreases at velocities going near to *c*. Pekka Pyykko has shown that this entails a contraction of the relativistic electron orbitals. And this contraction is proportional to the sum of the two quantum number *n* and *l*.

Mercury has the configuration {$\ce{Xe}$} $\ce{4f^{14} 5d^7 6s^2}$. The three external orbital have a sum *n+l* equal to $8$ for $4$f, $8$ for $5$d, and $7$ for $6$s. So the electron $4$f and $5$d (with *n+l* = $8$) are so much contracted that they nearly disappear in the internal core of electrons. It must be nearly the same for the $6$s electrons. And the mercury atom looks a bit like Xenon when seen from outside. That is why it is "nearly" a noble gas : its boiling point is rather low with respect to its neighboring atoms.

All the chemical properties of Mercury are due to its two $6$s electrons which are rather difficult to extract, as they are partly included in the inner core. These electrons "prefer" making covalent bonds rather than ionic bonds, when included in molecules with $\ce{CN}$ group or $\ce{Cl}$ atoms.

Pekka Pyykko, Relativity and the Periodic System of Elements, Accounts of Chemical Research, Vol. 12, No. 8, (1979), p. 276 - 281.

Comment: @Poutnik. All I can say is that your interpretation is not Pekka Pyykko's opinion.

Comment: "Dirac's opinion on the role relativistic quantum mechanics would play for chemical systems is wrong for two reasons. First, electrons in s and p atomic orbitals travel at a significant fraction of the speed of light. Second, relativistic effects cause indirect consequences that are especially evident for d and f atomic orbitals."

Pyykkö, Pekka (1988). "Relativistic effects in structural chemistry". Chemical Reviews. 88 (3): 563–594. doi:10.1021/cr00085a006.

Comment: @Poutnik So you are saying that the importance of Quantum/relativistic effects is overstated in Chemistry?

Comment: @Alan Whitteaker Not at all. How did you came to such conclusion ?

Comment: @Poutnik I thought so because of the way your comment was structured.

Comment: @Alan Whitteaker Well, non relativistic quantum computation of mercury melting point provides the result +80 Deg C. Relativistic one has the error within 1 Deg C. Make your conclusion.

Comment: "In all elements with atomic number higher than 70, the outer electrons move at a speed that is not far from c, the velocity of light in vacuum.".  No.  It is the innermost 1s electrons that acquire significantly relativistic mechanics.  The effect of that condition then cascades into the quantum states of all the other electrons even though the latter are not themselves strongly relativistic.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi. Pekka Pyykkö says exactly the contrary in his publications. He says that the outer electrons are "buried" in the inner core of the heavy atoms. And this explain why Mercury is "nearly" a noble gas (boils at low temperature, produces dimeric $\ce{Hg_2^{2+}}$ ions, like noble gases), why Thallium has often +1 as oxidation number (like alcaline metals, may replace K in alums) , why Lead often behaves like an alkaline earth metal ( Oxidation +2, insoluble PbSO4), etc.

Comment: Yes the outer (s) electrons are buried, but those are not the relativistic ones.  Outer electrons, even if they are buried, are not buried deeply enough to draw as much energy from the electrostatic field as their own mass energy, which is what would make them relativistic.  The _really_ buried inner s electrons are the relativistic ones.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi. If the outer electrons are buried in the core of the atom, that is a proof that they are relativistic. If they were not relativistic, they would have remained in the outer layers.

Comment: Cannot come to agreement and I don't want to be dinged for an extended discussion.  So I'm out.